# margin-top is not being applied on the first item of unordered list

Tags: html, css

**The output I got**
[image]

While trying out some CSS properties, I've observed that `margin-top` wasn't working on `item A`. Below is the code I've used for testing:

```css
ul {
  background-color : #295580;
  width            : 190px;
  border-radius    : 6px;
}

ul>li {
  background-color : #d9e8f7;
  margin-top       : 20px; /*/ Tried to apply margin-top on each <li> item */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item A</li>
  <li>item B</li>
  <li>item C</li>
  <li>item D</li>
  <li>item E</li>
</ul>
```

Actually I was trying to add margin on top of each `<li>` child.
So my question is why `margin-top` is being applied to all items(i.e. From item B to item E) except `item A`? Is it because of `margin collapse` or is there another reason behind it?

Comment: Yes that happens because of margin collapsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Proof that the margin is there]

The margin **IS** being applied. However, it is not visible since it the `ul` collapses the margin. You can apply `padding-top` to the `ul` element and the margin will not collapse.

```css
ul {
  background-color : #295580;
  width            : 190px;
  border-radius    : 6px;
  padding-top      : 0.1px;
}
```